# Access-Control-Allow-Origin error during token generation in OWIN enabled application

Tags: cors, asp.net-web-api2, access-token, access-control, owin-middleware

I am using C# Web API + CORS + Owin from Angular 8 application. I am getting below error while generating the token. I looked at variuos articles but I could not solve the problem.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:60544/Token' from origin
>   'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

**Global.asax.cs**

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
           // AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);   
        }

        protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {                
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {                    
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, No-Auth");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {            
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            var myProvider = new AuthorizationServerProvider();
            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions options = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                Provider = myProvider
            };
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(options);

            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

        }
```

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {            
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Filters.Add(new LoggingFilterAttribute());
            config.Filters.Add(new CustomExceptionFilterAttribute());

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
            config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings =
            new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
                DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc,
            };
        }
```

**web.config**

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="30000000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>    
  </system.webServer>
```

Following references have already been added in my solution:-

- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin
- Microsoft.Owin Microsoft.Owin.Cors
- Microsoft.Owin.Security
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth

Please help me in resolving this.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this by adding in your web.config file remove this from Application_Begin Request, i think this might work for you.

```
 <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

I have experienced the same thing in my side by i got it resolved by doing this.

Comment: Doing so giving me following error:-  "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status."

Comment: Hi @simpleuser, now you are getting some other error.